# Proof verification for $A \subset B$ iff $A - B = \varnothing$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to write a proof for

$$A \subset B\quad\text{if and only if}\quad A - B = \varnothing$$

Starting from the left side:

$$x \in A \subset B$$
$$x \in A \land x \in B$$
$$x \in A \cap B$$

Starting from the right side:

$$x \in A - B$$
$$x \in A \land x \notin B$$
$$x \in A \land x \in B'$$
$$x \in A \cap B'$$

Putting these two together:

$$x \in A \cap B \land x \in A \cap B'$$
$$x \in A \cap (B \cap B')$$
$$x \in A \cap \varnothing$$
$$x \in \varnothing$$

Is it correct?

Comment: Your first two lines do not even make sense. In the first three lines you have shown that $x \in A \land A \subset B$ implies $x \in A \cap B$, which is quite unrelated to what you want.

Comment: I always found $A-B$ to be a finmy notation for sets since we're showing $A$ is inside $B$. Technically A "subset" of B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only made an insufficient effort to prove $A\subseteq B\implies A-B=\varnothing$, and said nothing about the other side.

You proved that $A-B=A\cap B^c$.

The right way to go on is assuming that $x\in A-B$ and to deduce on that - combined with $A\subseteq B$ - a contradiction (which would indeed allow the conclusion that $A-B=\varnothing$).

This by observing that $x\in A-B$ implies $x\in B$ (on base of $A-B\subseteq A\subseteq B$) and also implies $x\in B^c$ (on base of $A-B=A\cap B^c\subseteq B^c$).

Comment: It is not clear to me why $A - B \subset A \subset B$, proving from right to left. Should not $A \subset B$ be the conclusion of the proof from right to left?

Answer (score 1):

No. You Indeed you are proving that, independently how is the relation between $A$ and $B$, $(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap B^\prime)=\emptyset$, which is not the excercise.

For your excercise:

$\Rightarrow$] You must take $x\in A$ and prove that $x\in B$ given $A-B=\emptyset$: Suppose, by contradiction, $x\notin B$. Then $x\in A$ and $x\in B^\prime$. Thus $x\in A\cap B^\prime$. But, by definition, the last set is precisely $A-B$. Then $x\in A-B$. Thus $A-B\neq\emptyset$, which is a contradiction by suppose $x\notin B$. So $x\in B$, which proves the first statement.

$\Leftarrow$] Can you continue?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems:

$$"x \in A \subset B$$
$$x \in A \land x \in B$$
$$x \in A \cap B"$$

Checks out, but a clearer argument is $x \in A$ and $A \subset B \implies x \in B$.

Now:

$$"x \in A - B$$
$$x \in A \land x \notin B$$
$$x \in A \land x \in B'$$
$$x \in A \cap B'"$$

Since $A \subseteq B$, Since $x \in B$ for all $x \in A$, your argument should be: $x \in A-B \implies x \notin A-B$.

In other words, $A \subseteq B$ implies that $A-B$ is empty.

Putting these two together:

$$"x \in A \cap B \land x \in A \cap B'$$
$$x \in A \cap (B \cap B')$$
$$x \in A \cap \varnothing$$
$$x \in \varnothing"$$

x cannot be in the empty set. This violates the definition of the empty set.

Consider this:

Suppose that $A-B= \emptyset$. Let $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{3,4\}$. Then $A-B=\emptyset$, but $A$ is not a subset of $B$. Thus, this proposition is false.

On the other hand, suppose that $A \subseteq B$.

Trivially, $\emptyset \subseteq A-B$. Now we want to show that $A-B \subseteq \emptyset$.

Suppose that $x \in A-B$. Then $x \in A$ and $x \notin B$. But, since $x \in A \implies x \in B$, this is a contradiction. Thus there is no such $x$. The result follows.(

Answer (score 0):

You need to focus on your goal. It might help to write down your assumptions. For instance, if you go from left to right, then you assume that $A⊂B$ and need to deduce that $A−B=∅$. A good way to stay tuned is to keep a clean page with the less abstract definitions.

Write $A−B=∅\mbox{ if }x∈A\Rightarrow x∈B$

$A⊂B \mbox{ if... }$

once you clearly define your definition and intention the prof will come naturally.

In your proof you assumed that $A⊂B$ , and deduced that $A∩(A−B)=∅$ (you stated that $x∈A\mbox{ and }x∈(A−B)\Rightarrow x$ cannot exist) . That is pretty close, and you are almost done (with the "if" part, you will still have the "and only if").

However, there are a lot of confusing steps in your proof and i encourage you to edit it once you are done. Try to done each side down to at max 5 lines.